# Windows Server 2012 R2 application installation slowness

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Good afternoon,

- Windows Server 2012 R2 as host fully up to date
- Windows Server 2012 R2 as guest fully up to date

Whether I am running it as a host or guest, whenever I am installing an application that should take a couple minutes it always ends up 3x-5x longer than it should. If I take the same applications and install it on any other OS (IE 2k8, 7,) it they install very quickly. Dell server management software took 30 minutes or so when it takes 5 minutes or so on 2k8. Even a clean install not joined to domain I still experience this same slowness on applications I attempt to install.

So my question to everyone is, are you or anyone else experiencing this? I cannot find anything on google so this is why I am here

Comment: What does your monitoring system tell you about system load and resource contention during the install process?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. Performance wise cpu/memory are barely being utilized, nothing in the event logs, and system(s) are running nothing else.